# using a loop to insert values from a column from a data frame into a dictionary key

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, dictionary

There are around 60.000 dictionaries stored in a list. There is also a dataframe with the same amount of rows of which I want to take one column and insert into the dictionaries as a key value pair.
I have created a for loop which is supposed to update dictionary values, which however seems to take forever. I am looking for a more optimal way to succeed considering the amount of rows.

```
new_dicties = []
for i in list_of_dicts:
    for x in resultsDf0['created_at']:
        i['created_at']=x
        new_dicties.append(i)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of elements in `list_of_dicts` and `resultsDf0`? Do they have any common key between them?

Comment: Your inner loop looks wrong. *i['created_at']=x* will repeatedly overwrite the value associated with the 'created_at' key then *new_dicties* will contains as many duplicated dictionaries as there are results returned from *resultsDf0['created_at']*. If *resultsDf0['created_at']* is only ever going to return one value then acquire that outside of the loop. Also, why create a new list? You're already modifying the dictionaries in the original list

Comment: You are actually doing 2 things: You update the dictionaries in `list_of_dicts` **and** put them (repeatedly) then into the new list `new_dicties` (rule of thumb in Python: variables are references).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the nested loop and based on the information you've given you are doing 60,000 x 60,000 = 3,600,000,000 dictionary updates, most of them in vain because you're overriding each update 59,999 times.

So I suspect you have the following situation: A dataframe `df` and a list of dictionaries `list_of_dicts` that have the same length (length of `df` = number of rows), for instance:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"created_at": ["2023-01-01", "2023-01-02", "2023-01-03"]})
list_of_dicts = [{"key": i} for i in range(1, 4)]
```

Most likely you're trying to do:

```py
new_dicties = []
for d, v in zip(list_of_dicts, df["created_at"]):
    d["created_at"] = v
    new_dicties.append(d)
```

Now this gives you the following `new_dicties`

```py
[{'key': 1, 'created_at': '2023-01-01'},
 {'key': 2, 'created_at': '2023-01-02'},
 {'key': 3, 'created_at': '2023-01-03'}]
```

**but** `list_of_dicts` looks the same, because the variables are references (pointers, if you will).

If that's fine, then you could also just stick with the original `list_of_dicts` and do

```py
for d, v in zip(list_of_dicts, df["created_at"]):
    d["created_at"] = v
new_dicties = list_of_dicts  # Maybe not needed
```

If that's not what you want, then you could do either

```py
new_dicties = [d | {"created_at": v} for d, v in zip(list_of_dicts, df["created_at"])]
```

in case you have Python 3.9 or higher or

```py
new_dicties = []
for d, v in zip(list_of_dicts, df["created_at"]):
    d = dict(d)
    d["created_at"] = v
    new_dicties.append(d)
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
new_dicties = []
for i in list_of_dicts:
    for j in i.keys():
        new_dicties.append(j)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.